# How to make a variable be interpreted as a function / command in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a variable be interpreted as a command.
So

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  opp := 'add' ;    
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender : TObject);
begin
  opp := 'sub'
end           

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender : TObject);
var
  op1, op2: Integer;
begin
  op1 := 1;        
  op2 := 1;
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(opp(op1,op2));
end;
```

Comment: How do you expect us to know what you are talking about?

Comment: maybe are you meaning [Procedural Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Procedural_Types)?

Comment: I see an accepted answer, you might be interested in an expression parser as well such as http://wiki.freepascal.org/How_To_Use_TFPExpressionParser

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a variable to a function obtaining something similar to what you want to achieve.

More about **Procedural types** [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Procedural_Types).

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  . . .
  private
    FOpp: function (AOp1, AOp2: Integer): Double;
  . . .
  end;

implementation

function OpAddFunction(AOp1, AOp2: Integer): Double;
begin
  Result := AOp1 + AOp2;
end;

function OpSubFunction(AOp1, AOp2: Integer): Double;
begin
  Result := AOp1 - AOp2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FOpp := OpAddFunction;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FOpp := OpSubFunction;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  op1, op2: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(FOpp) then
    Exit;
  op1 := 1;
  op2 := 2;
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(FOpp(op1, op2));
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Delphi ist no scripting language and everything gets compiled.

To interpret strings as delphi instructions, you need a script parser, for example [DWScript](https://www.delphitools.info/dwscript/).

Answer (score 0):

I assumed from the contents of your Button1Click and Button2Click handlers that you are asking how to invoke an arithmetic operation based on a textual operation of the operation's name.  So I'm a bit puzzled that you've accepted an answer which doesn't address that, but no matter.

As the other answer told you, Delphi is a compiler, not a script interpreter itself, but there are many Delphi implementations of them, and DWScript is a particularly fine and powerful example.

This answer focuses on invoking an arithmetic operation based on a textual operation of the operation's name.  This is, of course, only a small part of what a general purpose script interpreter (or, indeed, a simpler expression evaluator) does, but it is useful to know how you can do this invocation by textual name yourself without a whole cascade of "if OpName = 'xxx' then ... else if ..." statements.

In the code below, the TMethodWrapper class is used to store a reference to a particular integer operation (I've ignored Float/Double results for simplicity) and applies the operation to the invocation's arguments I1 & I2.  The arithmetic evaluation is done in its ApplyOperator method.

Then a TStringList, "OpList" is used as a "dictionary" to store the wrappers and the operation names.  The Button1Click handler looks up the operation named in Edit1.Text and applies it to the operation's arguments.

I've written this simple implementation so that it will work in D7.  Obviously with the generics facilities in more recent Delphi versions, it would be much easier to apply the principles involved to data types other than Integer, and you could use RTTI to add the functions and their names instead of how I've done it in FormCreate.  They also have objects like TDictionary that you could use in pace of a TStringList,

```
type

  TIntegerOperation = function(Int1, Int2 : Integer) : Integer of object;

  TMethodWrapper = Class
  private
    FOperation : TIntegerOperation;
  public
    constructor Create(AnOperation : TIntegerOperation);
    function GetValue(I1, I2 : Integer) : Integer;
    property Operation : TIntegerOperation read FOperation write FOperation;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    OpList : TStringList;
    function Add(I1, I2 : Integer): Integer;
    function Subtract(I1, I2 : Integer): Integer;
    procedure ApplyOperator(OpName: String; I1, I2 : Integer);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

function TForm1.Add(I1, I2 : Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result := I1 + I2;
end;

function TForm1.Subtract(I1, I2 : Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result := I1 - I2;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpList := TStringList.Create;

  OpList.AddObject('Add', TMethodWrapper.Create(Add));

  OpList.AddObject('Subtract', TMethodWrapper.Create(Subtract));

end;

constructor TMethodWrapper.Create(AnOperation: TIntegerOperation);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Operation := AnOperation;
end;

function TMethodWrapper.GetValue(I1, I2 : Integer): Integer;
var
  IntegerOperation : TIntegerOperation;
begin
  IntegerOperation := TIntegerOperation(Operation);
  Result := IntegerOperation(I1, I2);
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplyOperator(OpName : String; I1, I2 : Integer);
var
  Index : Integer;
  Res : Integer;
  MW : TMethodWrapper;
begin
  Index := OpList.IndexOf(OpName);
  if Index < 0 then Exit;
  MW := TMethodWrapper(OpList.Objects[Index]);
  Res := MW.GetValue(I1, I2);
  Caption := IntToStr(Res);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ApplyOperator(Edit1.Text, 3, 5);
end;
```